# How to use the value of a variable as key when constructing a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python , I want to make a dictionary using a formula in a loop.

My problem is that this code:

```
i = 1
A = {}
A.update(i=12)
print(A)
```

gives me `{'i': 12}`， while I want to get `{1: 12}`, with the value of `i` as key instead of its name. 
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation for dict.update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> update() accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of
>   key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two). If
>   keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with
>   those key/value pairs: d.update(red=1, blue=2).

If you use the syntax with keyword arguments, the names of the arguments will be used as keys.

In your case, as you want the value of `i` to be used, you want to use a `dict` as argument to `update`:

```
i=1
A={}
A.update({i:12})
print(A)

#{1: 12}
```

Comment: Why even use the `update()` method? You're doing it the hard way. Just do `A[i] = 12`.